# How Can I Edit Using Contenteditable On a Div With An Anchor Inside?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to make it so I can edit a div that has a string. If the string contains a link then the page will load with that link inside an anchor tag and allow it to be clicked on.

Below is the code that takes the post from the database, checks if there is a link and displays the link if it does (**EDIT**: I decided to change the php to javascript but now it doesn't update the database):

```
    <div id="reply<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>">
        <script>
            var text = "<?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?>";
            text = text.replace(/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?)/g,
            '<a href="$1" rel="nonfollow" target="_blank">$1</a>'
            );
            document.write(text);
        </script>
    </div>

        <?php
        if($editPost == true) {
            ?>
            <div id="postId"><?php echo $rows['id'];?></div>
            <button id="editPost">Edit</button>
            <button id="savePost">Save</button>
            <button id="cancelPost">Cancel</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(argument) {
                    $('#savePost').hide();
                    $('#cancelPost').hide();
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(argument) {
            $('#editPost').click(function() {
                $('#post').attr('contenteditable','true');
                $('#post').css('background','white');
                $('#post').css('border','solid 1px');
                $('#savePost').show();
                $('#cancelPost').show();
                $('#editPost').hide();
            });

            $('#savePost').click(function() {
                // Get edit field value
                $detail = $('#post').html();
                $id = $('#postId').html();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'editPost.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {detail: $detail, id: $id},
                    datatype: 'html',
                });

                $('#editPost').show();
                $('#savePost').hide();
                $('#cancelPost').hide();
                $('#post').attr('contenteditable','false');
                $('#post').css('background','#D8D8D8');
                $('#post').css('border','none');
            });

            $('#cancelPost').click(function() {
                $('#editPost').show();
                $('#savePost').hide();
                $('#cancelPost').hide();
                $('#post').attr('contenteditable','false');
                $('#post').css('background','#D8D8D8');
                $('#post').css('border','none');
            });
        });
    </script>
    ?>
```

editpost.php:

```
<?php
$host = "host"; // Host name 
$user = "username"; // Mysql username 
$password = "password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "fquestions"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Add your validation and save data to database

echo $detail;
echo $id;

$datetime = date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET detail = '$detail', datetime = 'Edited: $datetime' WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```

I can edit text without links just fine, but with the ones with an anchor inside it causes problems. I even have to use `<p>` instead of `<div>` or it doesn't display right even before editing.